# Pandas-datareader is installed, but can not be called

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am using Windows with Python 3.6, and so far with many other packages there was no problem running.

I am trying to install & use pandas-datareader, but after I installed it successfully:

```
> C:\Python36\Scripts>pip3 install pandas-datareader Collecting
> pandas-datareader   Using cached
> pandas_datareader-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Requirement already
> satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied: requests-ftp in
> c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas-datareader) Requirement
> already satisfied: pandas>=0.17.0 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages
> (from pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied: requests-file
> in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas-datareader) Requirement
> already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages
> (from requests>=2.3.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already
> satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> requests>=2.3.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied:
> urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> requests>=2.3.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied:
> chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> requests>=2.3.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied:
> numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas>=0.17.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied:
> pytz>=2011k in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas>=0.17.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied:
> python-dateutil>=2 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas>=0.17.0->pandas-datareader) Requirement already satisfied: six
> in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from
> requests-file->pandas-datareader) Installing collected packages:
> pandas-datareader Successfully installed pandas-datareader-0.5.0
```

when try to run it in both **pycharm / jupyter**, I receive:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

When I run the `pip3 list` in the cmd command, I can see it is installed (pandas (0.22.0) pandas-datareader (0.5.0)).

I went over many answers regarding this issue, but still could not resolve this.
Also, I am sure the directory is added to windows path.

Comment: pycharm/jupyter may be using a different version of python.

Comment: In your environment, run a quick program: ```import sys     for p in sys.path:  print(p)```.  Compare that to what you get on the command line.

Comment: @bigmacd the quick program run. i didn't understand what to compare in the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your environments, run a quick program:

```
import sys 
for p in sys.path: 
    print(p).
```

Compare those paths to where pip3 installed pandas_datareader, which is c:\python36\lib\site-packages

You may have to install it separately into PyCharm and jupyter